# Page layout setup

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm looking on Cnet's homepage and they have a cool over-lapping setup right now. [Click to see their homepage](http://cnet.com).

How exactly is this done?

I tried to figure it out, but I can't quite think of how to do it. Within my example the green would be the ad part on the Cnet homepage (with Zebras).

```css
#blue, #green, #red {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
#green {
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
#red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: The zebra is a fixed background image or a div with a image inside with a fixed property. Then the rest are just  a few divs (on top of the backgroun d) with a large space between them. The space between is transparent so you can see the background. Simple

Comment: I just can't get it to work for some reason. My green layer (zebra layer) doesn't show. https://jsfiddle.net/kL10Lvbg/3/

Comment: @sergiureznicencu Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a [codepen](http://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/QEEKvM)

```
    <div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="green">
      <label>ADD GOES HERE</label>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll">
      <div id="blue"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

css:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  .scroll {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  #blue,
  #green,
  #red,
  #yellow {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #blue {
    background: blue;
  }
  #green {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: green;
  }
  #red {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 500px;
  }
  #yellow {
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 500px;
  }
}
```

theres room to improve but the gist is that the advertisement (green div) is positioned absolutely on the same level as a div that wraps your scrollable items.

Comment: Actually I think I got it, but I didn't notice you had the `overflow: y-scroll`. That will not work. It needs to be a natural scroll like the example.